# How to get value of HTML Div using PHP

Tags: php, html

I have div which is `php`.It is given below.

```
$did = "<div id='primary'>value 110</div>";
```

I need value in some variable as `'value 110'` only.I don't want to use `Jquery`,`Ajax` or any other `javascript`.

I need the div value in `PHP` variable.

And Also the value inside Div which is 'value 110' is coming through Jquery.So it is run time value onclick of a edit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) may be what you need, give it a try.

Here's an example that shows how to edit an HTML element:

```
$html = str_get_html('<div id="hello">Hello</div><div id="world">World</div>');

$html->find('div', 1)->class = 'bar';

$html->find('div[id=hello]', 0)->innertext = 'foo';

echo $html; // Output: <div id="hello">foo</div><div id="world" class="bar">World</div>
```

From the example you can easily create the code that you need:

```
$html = str_get_html("<div id='primary'>value 110</div>");
$text = $html->find('div[id=primary]', 0)->innertext;
echo $text; // Prints "value 110", the content inside the div called "primary"
```

I haven't tried the code but I believe it shuold work.

Comment: Also the value inside Div which is 'value 110' is coming through Jquery.So it is run time value onclick of a edit button.

Comment: If the value is available only after the page loads I don't think you can access it by parsing HTML via PHP before the page is ready. You could make a hidden call via JavaScript/Ajax to a PHP page which processes the data. Can I ask you what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

use a function to make your divs

```
function divmaker($id, $value) 
{ 
echo '<div '; 
if(!empty($id))echo 'id='.$id;
echo '>'.$value.'</div>;
}
```

that way you can output divs and keep value separate