# check in PHP if html div equals a certain value

Tags: javascript, php

I'm making a webpage that should show a countdown, and if it comes to zero, the next countdown should start, with a new deadline.
Now, I've made the countdown part in Javascript, this works.
I've made a php part that reads the deadlines form a txt file, this also works.
Now I've found a way to transfer the php deadline to the javascript, should work.
But. 
the next deadline has to start when the previous one is done, so it's 00:00:00. 
is there a way to check the content of a html div in php?
So it would have to check if the content of the div with id=countdown equals 00:00:00

thanks guys! 
edit: the proposition duplicate question did not solve my problem...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- php functions -->
 <?php

$deadlineH = null;
$deadlineM = null;
$deadlineS = null;
$deadlineTitle = null;


$filename = "data.txt";
$fp = fopen($filename, "r");
$content = fread($fp, filesize($filename));

$fullArray = setFullArray($content);
$length = count($fullArray);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length - 1; $i++) {
  $value = $fullArray[$i];
  echo "var " . ($i + 1)  . ": " . $fullArray[$i] ." <br>";
  if((($i+1) % 4) == 0){
    echo "   ";
  }
}

$numberoflines = getNumberOflines($fullArray);
echo "number of lines: " . $numberoflines . "<br>";
showDeadlines($fullArray);

function setFullArray($content){
  $fullArray =  preg_split("/(:|\n)/" ,$content);         // splits the whole data txt file into small chunks, everything apart
  return $fullArray;
}

function getNumberOflines($fullArray){
  $numberoflines = (sizeof($fullArray) - 1) / 4;
  return $numberoflines;
}

function showDeadlines($fullArray){
  $length = count($fullArray);
  for ($i=0; $i < $length-1; $i =  $i + 4) {
    $deadlineNumber = ($i + 4)/4;
    $deadlineH = $fullArray[$i];
    $deadlineM = $fullArray[$i+1];
    $deadlineS = $fullArray[$i+2];
    $deadlineTitle = $fullArray[$i+3];
    echo "deadline " . $deadlineNumber . ": " . $deadlineH . ":" . $deadlineM . ":" . $deadlineS . " titel : " . $deadlineTitle . "<br>";
  }
}
?>
<!-- end php functions -->

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">

<?php
//php vars:
$NumberOfDeadlines = 10;
 ?>

<div id="visible">
<div id="clock"><span> </span> </div><br>
<div id="countdown"> </span> </div>
</div>
<div id="inputs">

  <form>
<!-- <?php
for ($i=1; $i < $NumberOfDeadlines; $i++) { ?>
  deadline <?= $i ?> : <br>
  <label for="deadline<?= $i ?>H">Hour: </label>
  <input type="number" name="deadline<?= $i ?>H" id="deadline<?= $i ?>H"  min="0" max="23">
  <label for="deadline<?= $i ?>M">Minute: </label>
  <input type="number" name="deadline<?= $i ?>M" id="deadline<?= $i ?>M" min="0" max="59">
  <label for="deadline<?= $i ?>S">Second: </label>
  <input type="number" name="deadline<?= $i ?>S" id="deadline<?= $i ?>S" min="0" max="59">
  <label for="deadline<?= $i ?>Title">Title: </label>
  <input type="text" name="deadline<?= $i ?>Title" id="deadline<?= $i ?>Title">
  <br>
<?php
}
 ?> -->
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>

<!-- javascript scripts -->
<script>
function startTime() {
    var now = new Date();
    //var deadline = new Date();                 NOT USED ANY MORE
    // year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds
    var deadline = new Date(2016, 11, 9);
    var phpHours = <?php echo json_encode($GLOBAL[deadlineH]); ?>;
    var phpMinutes = <?php echo json_encode($GLOBAL[deadlineM]); ?>;
    var phpSeconds = <?php echo json_encode($GLOBAL[deadlineS]); ?>;
    deadline.setHours()
    
    //console.log(deadline);

    var clockH = now.getHours();
    var clockM = now.getMinutes();
    var clockS = now.getSeconds();

    // var countdownH = getCountdown(deadline).hours;
    // var countdownM = getCountdown(deadline).minutes;
    // var countdownS = getCountdown(deadline).seconds;

    //m = checkTime(m);
    //s = checkTime(s);

    startClock('clock');
    startCountdown('countdown', deadline);

    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}

function getCountdown(deadline){
  //console.log(Date.parse(deadline));
  //console.log(Date.parse(new Date()));
    var countdownTotal =  Date.parse(deadline) - Date.parse(new Date());
    var countdownS =      Math.floor( (countdownTotal/1000) % 60 );
    var countdownM =      Math.floor( (countdownTotal/1000/60) % 60 );
    var countdownH =      Math.floor( (countdownTotal/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
    return{
      'countdownTotal':   countdownTotal,
      'countdownH':       countdownH,
      'countdownM':       countdownM,
      'countdownS':       countdownS
    }
}

function startClock(id){
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var timeInterval = setInterval(function(){
    var now = new Date();
    var nowH = now.getHours();
    var nowM = now.getMinutes();
    var nowS = now.getSeconds();
    nowH = checkTime(nowH);
    nowM = checkTime(nowM);
    nowS = checkTime(nowS);

    clock.innerHTML = nowH + ':' + nowM + ':' + nowS;
  }, 1000);
}

function startCountdown(id, deadline){
  var countdown = document.getElementById(id);
  var timeInterval = setInterval(function(){
    var t = getCountdown(deadline);
    //console.log(t);
    countdown.innerHTML = checkTime(t.countdownH) + ':' + checkTime(t.countdownM) + ':' + checkTime(t.countdownS);
    if(t.countdownTotal <= 0){
      clearInterval(timeInterval);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
</script>
<!-- //end javascript -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you would want to make an AJAX call and send the contents of the div to a php script for parsing/processing..

Comment: I added my code for the person who asked about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get value of HTML Div using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30569809/how-to-get-value-of-html-div-using-php)

Comment: that's right, I think, but however, the question was not solved there, the suggested approach was not followed to get the result, but another was , but this second one is not explained properly. If you can do this, by my guest! @HamzaZafeer

Answer (score 0):

Do you transfer all the countdown data to the html page ?
if yes, the active countdown must *fire an event when comes to end*. and if so, your next countdown have to be 'flagged'.
if no, and also, the countdown must fire an event, in that event, you can make an ajax call to server to get next countdown daba, or even refresh the page to get newest countdown.

**Edit :**

I know that programmers don't want to give up on their code, but i shall recommand you a countdown plugin, that supports end event and so much other features. You can fint it in [this link](http://metroui.org.ua/countdown.html).

Now, to get the next countdown data, as i already said, you have to make an ajax call when one ends, or to get all of them in page load.

I don't know if it's what you need, but i hope i will help.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can only read static pages using the php get_contents function, example:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/');
echo $homepage;
```

If you manipulate the data using javascript you can also use it to make an ajax request to send the contents of the div to your php script.